# How to retrieve a captured group regex in busybox sed

Tags: regex, sed, busybox

I'm making a script to boot a TS-7400 ARM SBC and I want it to be able to read some arguments and optional kernel parameters passed via a configuration file found on a SDcard. I called my config file `syscfg.conf` and it is organized using `KEYWORD=value` pairs, but since kernel arguments themselves can have the same syntax, I thought of delimiting values like this:

```
CMDLINE_ARGS="elevator=noop scheduler=noop"
```

While testing in regular bash, I was able to isolate the kernel command line arguments using either one of these methods:

```
$ grep CMDLINE_ARGS syscfg.conf | sed 's/CMDLINE_ARGS="\(.*\)"/\1/'
elevator=noop scheduler=noop

$ grep CMDLINE_ARGS syscfg.conf | cut -d'"' -f2
elevator=noop scheduler=noop

$ awk -F'"' '/CMDLINE_ARGS/ {print $2}' syscfg.conf
elevator=noop scheduler=noop
```

but when it runs on TS-LINUX, which is a busybox-based stripped down Linux used to boot a custom kernel or application, it doesn't work like in regular bash. While the `awk` command doesn't even exist, the `cut` version worked fine, but the `sed` one returns this:

```
CMDLINE_ARGS="elevator=noop scheduler=noop"
```

Why is busybox's `sed` implementation behaving like this? Instead of returning the whole string, I expected it to output only the "`\1`" group of any characters between the `"` delimiters - the `"(.*)"` regex. Is there any way we can make it work like in bash?

Comment: Your command works here, busybox version 1.20.2

Comment: Does it? I'll have to check which version TS-LINUX uses then... it looks VERY old (kernel 2.4 yet...)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/CMDLINE_ARGS=/ {s/CMDLINE_ARGS=.//;s/.$//;}' syscfg.conf
```

try maybe this if quote are problem or the pipe (i suspect shell substitution in one of those part)

Comment: Hmm. I'm on vacation right now, but as soon as I get back to work I'll try that. Thanks!